# Union select with variable, in PHP with PDO. How to do it right?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to run a query that returns a random row, and 2 rows surrounding that row (previous and next).

I have saved the random result value in a variable so it can be used by all the following queries.

My query is as follows:

```
SET @rand := (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * MAX(id)) FROM data); 
(SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` < @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` = @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) UNION
(SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` > @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1);
```

the @rand does contain a valid random ID.

It turns out to have been a display issue on the phpmyadmin interface I had been using from a university pc.

The query executes correctly and in the mysql command line interface the rows are shown correctly. However in PHP/pdo it now returns

```
PDOStatement::fetchAll(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
```

whereas the same code without @rand in the query and using a static id for testing purposes, it returns the 3 rows as expected.

Comment: Even if it contains a valid id _now_ you can't rely (usually) on ids being contiguous - values disappear if the DB goes down (especially if using caching for performance reasons), when inserts get rolled back, when a row gets deleted, etc.  So, the `=` comparison isn't going to work, really.  This also doesn't evenly distribute the selection - there are problems when the `=` comparison would be the top/bottom value.  What RDBMS?  And why do you want next/previous entries?

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.6, the reason I want previous / next values is because some rows have visibility 0 and others 1, Obviously I want only the first visible row surrounding each row. Perhaps I should edit the query in the question to show this (AND VISIBLE = 1). Let me know if there's anything more you want to know.

Comment: We may need to see your calling code; your query appears correct.    I can understand that you only want the first "visible" row, but (assuming filtering has already been done) why do you still want prev/next rows?  You can't guarantee any sort of relationship (or **non**-relationship) to the middle row.  If you need three random rows, re-order everything, then select (the top) three rows.  If there is supposed to be a relationship, you need to do more work to ensure it - MySQL may not have good support for this, depending on what you're attempting.

Comment: When you REPLACE a row with InnoDB engine, its ID gets resetted also. How about `SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 3, RAND()` or `SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 3 ORDER BY RAND()`?

Comment: I'm thinking that PDO might be having a problem running two queries. It's possible that it's returning the result of the first statement that sets the value of @rand.  Have you tried using a stored procedure instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that PDO is having trouble running two SQL statements. I would create a stored procedure to run the statements and use PDO to call the stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetThreeRandomRows()
BEGIN
    @rand := (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * MAX(id)) FROM data); 
    (SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` < @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) UNION 
    (SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` = @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) UNION
    (SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` > @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1);
END;
```

Then call it like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL spGetThreeRandomRows()");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: That approach indeed did the trick! It seems PDO did take the result from the first query. I had to change the @rand declaration to "SET @rand" though, but it worked! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You have set that query such that it will return at max 3 rows as you have used `LIMIT 1` for each 3 queries.

The other thing, despite this, you have also applied filtering to these query using

```
where id > @rand
```

So, how can you expect more than 3 rows ?

May be to get previous & next row, you can use this logic as,

```
SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` < @rand ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` = @rand LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `data` where `id` > @rand ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1
```

Will work little bit better.

Comment: ...The implication was that three rows were being selected, they just weren't being returned for some reason.  You can't rely on there being a row with an id matching the random number, much less immediate neighbors (ids will become non-contiguous at the most inopportune time).  What makes you think `where id > @rand` give him anything _less_ than the remaining rows with greater `id` values?  He has to order/limit to only get **1** row!

Comment: He is asking two questions. 1] Why I am getting only 3 rows ? & 2] How can I get previous & next row, & assuming this I have suggested ID IN (@rand+1),(@rand-1),(@rand).

Comment: ...Uh, he's _trying_ to get three rows, and the original post indicates to me he knows that his current efforts will have that effect (they just aren't being returned).  His current version should return the next/prev row (regardless of whether the middle row is returned) - your version will work less often than his will!  When there's only one value, `IN` is functionally identical to `=` (and may be optimized that way) - why did you think this version would help?

Comment: Hm, the query is essentially unchanged, so I don't expect this to actually solve his problem.  Although looking at what you've got, you've probably fixed a problem I didn't notice - he was getting the _last_ row (always!) as opposed to the **next** row (due to sort order).  I still suspect something in whatever he's using to perform the query.  Oh, and if there's more than one row with an identical primary key, there's usually a big problem...

Comment: I figured out the issue, it turned out phpmyadmin that I was using from a university pc didn't actually spit out the records, I tried again in mysql console and it showed them just fine. And you were indeed right that I forgot about the third row always being the last. I fixed that as well. However I'm now stuck with an issue in PHP/PDO where this query doesn't return any rows and returns HY000 General error, the same query without the variable returns the 3 records as an object just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result by this way

```
SELECT * 
FROM `data` 
where `id` between @rand-1 and @rand+
```

Ok. Then you can try this

```
SET @rand := (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * MAX(id)) FROM data);

 SELECT top 1 * FROM `data` where `id` < @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC
 UNION 
 SELECT top 1 * FROM `data` where `id` = @rand AND safe = 1 
 UNION 
 SELECT top 1 * FROM `data` where `id` > @rand AND safe = 1 ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: This won't help long term - you can't rely on ids being contiguous.  It also has problems at the end-points, when `@rand` ends up being the top/bottom value (or below the bottom value, even!).  `BETWEEN` should be avoided in favor of explicitly defined ranges in any case (and with an exclusive upper-bound when possible)